# What does waitpid() do?

Tags: linux, unix, posix

What is the use of `waitpid()`?

Answer (score 10):

It's used generally to wait until a specific process finishes (or otherwise changes state if you're using special flags), based on its process ID (otherwise known as a `pid`).

It can also be used to wait for any of a group of child processes, either one from a specific process group or any child of the current process.

See [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) for the gory details.

Answer (score 8):

It blocks the calling process until a nominated child process exits (or makes some other transition such as being stopped.)

Typically you will use `waitpid` rather than generic `wait` when you may have more than one process and only care about one.

A typical use is

```c
pid_t child_pid;
int status;

child_pid = fork();

if (child_pid == 0) {
     // in child; do stuff including perhaps exec
} else if (child_pid == -1) {
     // failed to fork 
} else {
     if (waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0) == child_pid) {
          // child exited or interrupted; now you can do something with status
     } else {
          // error etc
     }
 }
```